# When should a question be asked on (operating system).stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, posting

I had asked a question awhile ago about packaging an app with drag-drop ability in Unity:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999552/enable-drag-and-drop-ubuntu-unity

It was closed as misplaced, should have been on the Ubuntu stack-exchange.

However, I have seen numerous questions on iOS/Apple, even some specifically related to packaging, that are not flagged or moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com.

[Create drag-drop graphic when installing OS X application from dmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871199/create-drag-drop-graphic-when-installing-os-x-application-from-dmg)

[missing Java library Mac osx AIR Developer Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675095/missing-java-library-mac-osx-air-developer-tool)

[Mac app package. Is this normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954280/mac-app-package-is-this-normal)

for example. I was wondering if there is a specific policy about when a packaging question should be flagged/moved to the Android/Apple/Ubuntu/etc. site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ask Different site is a *end user* Q&A site. Questions about developing software *for* the Apple platform are on-topic for Stack Overflow, and not for Ask Different.

You need to check out the FAQ for each individual site to see what is considered on topic there. There is no hard and fast rule.

From the [Ask Different FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for example:

> Ask Different is for **Apple enthusiasts and power users**.
>
> (...) Please **refrain from asking** about ...
>
> - programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator

so programming questions are *specifically off topic* for that site.

The [Ubuntu FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) on the other hand explicitly *includes* development:

> We welcome questions about: (...)
>
> - Development on Ubuntu.